# Erro Champ inconnu dans on clause - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tenho a seguinte situação, com 3 tabelas:

`ocorrencias`: Possui 6 colunas: `tipo_falha_1` até `tipo_falha_6`. É um código de 2 digitos, de 1 até 20.

`tipo_falha`: Possui a descrição das falhas. O campo `cod` é ligado a ocorrências pelo `tipo_falha` acima citado. Além disso, possui a coluna `tipo_servico` com um código que vincula ao tipo de serviço. Exemplo: Falha elétrica(`tipo_falha`), Elétrico (`tipo_servico`).

`tipo_servico`: Possui a descrição do servico cujo tipo_falha aponta. O campo cod é ligado a tipo_servico da tabela tipo_falha.

Minha necessidade seria gerar uma consulta, com 6 colunas, dos tipos de falha do 1 até o 6, trazendo resultado onde tiver dado e `null` onde não tiver nada. Tentei o SQL abaixo, mas está retornando o erro:

```
#1054 - Champ 'o.tipo_falha_1' inconnu dans on clause.
```

O que posso estar fazendo errado?

```
SELECT tf1.NOME desc1, tf2.NOME AS desc2, tf3.NOME AS desc3, tf4.NOME AS desc4, tf5.NOME AS desc5, tf6.NOME AS desc6
               FROM ocorrencias o, tipo_servico ts LEFT JOIN
               tipo_falha tf1
               on tf1.cod = o.tipo_falha_1 LEFT JOIN
               tipo_falha tf2
               on tf2.cod = o.tipo_falha_2 LEFT JOIN
               tipo_falha tf3
               on tf3.cod = o.tipo_falha_3 LEFT JOIN
               tipo_falha tf4
               on tf4.cod = o.tipo_falha_4 LEFT JOIN
               tipo_falha tf5
               on tf5.cod = o.tipo_falha_5 LEFT JOIN    
               tipo_falha tf6
               on tf6.cod = o.tipo_falha_6
               where
               o.cod= 1
```

Comment: Tu tá vendo que tu tá dizendo pra dar `LEFT JOIN` de `tipo_servico` ligando pela `ocorrencias`, e depois não tem join nenhum pela `ts` né? Se funcionasse, provavelmente iria trazer uma lambança no resultado final. Acredito que só inverter a ordem do `ts` pelo `o` não vai resolver, é melhor dar uma olhada na estrutura da tabela, porque isso só iria dar erro se a tabela não possuísse esse campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo um LEFT JOIN de tipo_falha com tipo_servico, mas a condição do join usa um campo que está em ocorrencias.

```
  FROM ocorrencias o, tipo_servico ts LEFT JOIN
               tipo_falha tf1
               on tf1.cod = o.tipo_falha_1
```

Já que você não usa tipo_servico para nada, por que você não faz assim?

```
  FROM ocorrencias o LEFT JOIN
               tipo_falha tf1
               on tf1.cod = o.tipo_falha_1
```